# How to show selection marker on EditText

Tags: android

In my app I programmatically set start and end selection on EditText via setSelection(int start, int end) method, but user doesn't see selection markers. How can I show markers programmatically?
When I said marker I mean this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer. Hope it will help someone. Need use method show when need show pins and in onSelectionChange need use hidePins, because pins don't hide after used showPins.

```
public void showPins() {
    Class TV = TextView.class;
    try {
        Field GetEditor = TV.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        GetEditor.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = GetEditor.get(this);
        Method GetInsController = editor.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSelectionController");
        GetInsController.setAccessible(true);
        Object insController = GetInsController.invoke(editor);
        if (insController != null) {
            Method Show = insController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("show");
            Show.setAccessible(true);
            Show.invoke(insController);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void hideTwoPins() {
    Class TV = TextView.class;
    try {
        Field GetEditor = TV.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        GetEditor.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = GetEditor.get(this);
        Method GetInsController = editor.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSelectionController");
        GetInsController.setAccessible(true);

        Object insController = GetInsController.invoke(editor);
        if (insController != null) {
            Method hide = insController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hide");
            hide.setAccessible(true);
            hide.invoke(insController);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

custom method

```
/**
       * Method allocates filtering substring in all contacts yellow color,
       * that satisfy the user's search 
       * @param inputText - DisplayName
       *        filtText - filtering Text
       * @return String with allocating substring (Spannable)
       */
    public static Spannable changeBackgroungFiltText(CharSequence inputText, String filtText, int color) {
        Spannable str = null;
      if(inputText != null)
      {
        String inputStr = inputText.toString();
        String inputLowerCaseStr = inputStr.toLowerCase();
        String filtLowerCaseStr = filtText.toLowerCase();
//      Spannable str = new SpannableStringBuilder(inputStr);
            str = new SpannableStringBuilder(inputStr); 
        if (filtText.length() != 0)
         {
             int indexStart = 0;
             while (true)
             {
                 int indexCur = inputLowerCaseStr.indexOf(filtLowerCaseStr, indexStart);
                 if (indexCur != -1) {
                     int start = indexCur;
                     int end = indexCur + filtText.length();
                     int flag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;
                     str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color),start, end, flag);
                     //str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(highlightColor), start, end, flag);
                     indexStart = indexCur + 1;
                 } else {
                     return str;
                 }
             }           
         } else {
             return str;
         }
      }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but you incorrect understand me. I updated the question

Comment: i think that there is not special method for this. 
Maybe reflection can help you.
android source - http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to show the left or right pin**,

based on the code of the second post (thanks a lot by the way).

```
    public static void showSelectionPins(TextView textView, boolean left, boolean right) {
        Class TV = TextView.class;
        try {
            Field GetEditor = TV.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
            GetEditor.setAccessible(true);
            Object editor = GetEditor.get(textView);
            Method GetInsController = editor.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSelectionController");
            GetInsController.setAccessible(true);
            Object insController = GetInsController.invoke(editor);
            if (insController != null) {
                Method Show = insController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("show");
                Show.setAccessible(true);
                Show.invoke(insController);
            }
            /**
             * since the {@code mStartHandle} and {@code mEndHandle} are created lazily<br/>
             * we must access them after {@code show()} has been called.
             */
            if (!left) {
                Field SelectionStartHandleView = insController.getClass().getDeclaredField("mStartHandle");
                SelectionStartHandleView.setAccessible(true);
                Object startHandleView = SelectionStartHandleView.get(insController);
                Method handleViewHideMethod = startHandleView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("hide");
                handleViewHideMethod.setAccessible(true);
                handleViewHideMethod.invoke(startHandleView);
            }
            if (!right) {
                Field SelectionEndHandleView = insController.getClass().getDeclaredField("mEndHandle");
                SelectionEndHandleView.setAccessible(true);
                Object endHandleView = SelectionEndHandleView.get(insController);
                Method handleViewHideMethod = endHandleView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("hide");
                handleViewHideMethod.setAccessible(true);
                handleViewHideMethod.invoke(endHandleView);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Here is how to show the insertion pin**,

also based on the code of the second post (thanks a lot by the way).

```
    public static void showInsertionPin(TextView textView) {
        Class TV = TextView.class;
        try {
            Field GetEditor = TV.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
            GetEditor.setAccessible(true);
            Object editor = GetEditor.get(textView);
            Method GetInsertionPointCursorController = editor.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getInsertionController");
            GetInsertionPointCursorController.setAccessible(true);

            Object insController = GetInsertionPointCursorController.invoke(editor);
            if (insController != null) {
                Method hide = insController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("show");
                hide.setAccessible(true);
                hide.invoke(insController);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```